# How to pass control characters, e.g. <c-e> to a function in a mapping?

Tags: vimscript, functions

I often find myself accidentally pressing `<c-e>`/`^E` while in normal mode inside a terminal buffer. This causes the terminal buffer to scroll down and a line with a `~` is displayed, like when your file doesn't reach the bottom of the screen.

I've created a mapping that stops `^E` from being called if the current buffer is a terminal.

```
nnoremap ^E :call ScrollStop()<cr>
function! ScrollStop()
  if &buftype !=# "terminal"
    normal! ^E
  endif
endfunction
```

I would now like to do the same thing for `^Y` by extending the function to allow me to pass in either `^E` or `^Y` but all my attempts so far have caused various errors, mainly `E119: Not enough arguments for function: ScrollStop`.

---

Thanks to the comments by @GaryJohn we've narrowed the problem down.  If we have the following function:

```
function! MyScroll(key)
   exe 'normal' a:key
endfunction
```

and we call it via `:call MyScroll('^E')` where `^E` is entered via ctrl-v + crtl-e then we get the expected result, the buffer scrolls down one line.

If however we create a mapping `:nnoremap ^E :call MyScroll('^E')<cr>` then press `^E`, we get an error `E471: Argument required: normal`. This happens for both Vim and Neovim.

Comment: What editor are you using? There is no mention of a "terminal" buftype in the Vim reference manual.

Comment: I don't consider this an actual answer to your question, but since you'll be defining maps for both `^E` and `^Y`, why could you just not call the function with `:call ScrollStop('E')` and `:call ScrollStop('Y')` respectively? Why would it need to be the control character and not just a string?

Comment: @garyjohn, I'm using Neovim but the question isn't specific to terminal buffers.

Comment: @SakariCajanus certainly I can do that and then just have an if statement in my function but I'd like to know if there is a way to just pass the control-character so I don't need to add the if statements, which saves a small amount of code in my trivial example but could be useful in other cases

Comment: It's true that the answer isn't specific to terminal buffers, but it _is_ specific to the editor, and it _could_ depend on differences between Neovim and Vim. The following works with Vim and may work with Neovim as well. `:function MyScroll(key)` `:exe 'normal' a:key` `:endfunction` `:call MyScroll('^E')` where I entered `^E` by typing `Ctrl-V Ctrl-E`.

Comment: @garyjohn, your MyScroll function works in both Vim and Neovim when called from the command prompt. It only when I try and make a mapping that it stops working (for both Vim and Neovim). You've help me narrow the issue though so thanks for that!

Comment: you need to use `:norm! key` (so be sure to use the **!** for the `:norm` command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want to use:

```
nmap <expr> <c-e> &buftype !=# 'terminal' ? "\<c-e>" : ''
```

To make this more convenient:

```
function! s:terminal_ignore(key, ...) abort
  execute printf('nmap <expr> %s &buftype !=# "terminal" ? "%s" : "%s"',
        \ a:key, a:key, a:0 ? a:1 : '')
endfunction

call s:terminal_ignore("\<c-e>")
call s:terminal_ignore("\<c-y>")
```

This uses `:h map-<expr>` to check `&buftype`.  If it's `terminal`, return an empty string, which is noop.

A few things to note:

- This is compatible with Vim.
- `nmap` is used instead of `nnoremap`.  It doesn't matter in the above script since it's returning the same key for non-terminal buffers. However, if you decide that the expression should return something else for the terminal, you will want it to be recursive.
- The returned string *must* be a constant string (`:h expr-quote`).  `"\<c-e>"` is <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd>/`^E`, `'<c-e>'` is literally `<c-e>`.  In the `s:terminal_ignore()` function, the constant string `"\<c-e>"` is passed so that it can be used in `{lhs}` and `{rhs}`.  Only `{lhs}` will evaluate `<c-e>` as <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd>, but it works fine with a constant string.  `{rhs}` is used literally.
- You can pass an optional second argument that will be used if the current buffer is a terminal.  e.g. `call s:terminal_ignore("\<c-e>", "A<c-e>")` to put the terminal back into insert mode and type <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd>.
- I'm using `<c-e>` instead of the literal `^E` because I want my scripts to be legible in non-vim programs.

Answer (score 2):

The following function and calls to that function work in Vim. It seems like they should work in Neovim but I don't have a Neovim to test.

```
function MyScroll(key)
    exe 'normal' a:key
endfunction

call MyScroll('^E')
call MyScroll('^Y')
```

where the `^E` and `^Y` in the calls to MyScroll() above are literal `Ctrl-E` and `Ctrl-Y` characters entered by typing the two-character sequences `Ctrl-V Ctrl-E` and `Ctrl-V Ctrl-Y`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You want `normal!` so you don't call your own mapping recursively:

```
:norm[al][!] {commands}                                 :norm :normal
                        Execute Normal mode commands {commands}.  This makes
                        it possible to execute Normal mode commands typed on
                        the command-line.  {commands} are executed like they
                        are typed.  For undo all commands are undone together.
                        Execution stops when an error is encountered.

                        If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used.
                        Without it, when this command is called from a
                        non-remappable mapping (:noremap), the argument can
                        be mapped anyway.
```

So your function should be:

```
function! MyScroll(key)
   exe 'normal!' a:key
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variation of [garyjohn's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5776/343) which removes the requirement to enter control characters directly into your Vimscript by adding the `Ctrl` modifier *inside* the function.

```
function! ScrollStop(key)
  if &buftype !=# "terminal"
    execute 'normal! ' . nr2char(and(char2nr(a:key), "0b0011111"))
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-E> :call ScrollStop('E')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <C-Y> :call ScrollStop('Y')<cr>
```

It takes advantage of the way the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key was implemented historically in terminals: by clearing the 6th and 7th bits of the ASCII character: we do this by `and`-ing with the binary value `0011111`

(I could also have used the expression`nr2char(toupper(char2nr(a:key)) - 64)`. Ctrl-modified keystrokes are always 64 spots below the upper-case version of the unmodified keystroke: converting to upper-case is the same as clearing the 6th bit; subtracting 64 is the same as clearing the 7th.)